# Bootstrap modal open exactly over modal not on full window

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using bootstrap modal. I am opening a bootstrap modal over a modal, but it open exactly over another modal, not on full window. so when I click on cancel button it closes both modals.

Comment: show your efforts so will get have idea

Comment: We need extra info to help you. Please, put your code. Regards

Comment: <div class="modal fade" id="taskModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="taskModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 90%;">
        <div class="container modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               

            </div>   
                                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: Please edit it in your question and format it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with giving width and height for one modal.So you can get one modal window extend it will be easier for you to close.
Use with Styles like:
.modal-body {position: relative;overflow-y: auto;max-height: 400px;padding: 15px;}